# How to shows CPT which has specific meta key?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, meta-query

I am trying to show post from CPT, but it shows no records.I want to show posts which has meta_key:`match_details_competition_name` and `match_details_session_name`.Hollowing are my codes.

```
  function my_custom_leauge_table(){

     $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
         // meta query
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'match_details_competition_name',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'match_details_session_name',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),

    )

    );  

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);


    $temp_teams_home=array();
    $temp_teams_away=array();
    $winning_team=array();
    $losing_team=array();
    $drawn_team=array();
    $league_ids=array();
    $season_ids=array();
    $total_goals=[];
    //$totalrows_count=0;

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();




        $temp_teams_home[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_home_team', true );
        $temp_teams_away[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_away_team', true );
        $home_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_home_team', true );
        $away_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_away_team', true );

        $home_goals = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_goals_scored_home_team', true );
        $away_goals = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'match_details_goals_scored_away_team', true );
        //$competition_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'match_details_competition_name', true );


        if($home_goals > $away_goals){
            $winning_team[]=$home_team;
            $losing_team[]=$away_team;          
        } 
        if($home_goals < $away_goals){
            $winning_team[]=$away_team;
            $losing_team[]=$home_team;
        } 
        if($home_goals == $away_goals){
            $drawn_team[]=$home_team;
            $drawn_team[]=$away_team;
        }           

        $total_goals_scored[]=array($home_team=>$home_goals,$away_team=>$away_goals);
        $total_goals_condeded[]=array($home_team=>$away_goals,$away_team=>$home_goals);
        //$totalrows_count++;


    endwhile;


    $total_matches_played = array_count_values(array_merge($temp_teams_home,$temp_teams_away));
    $team_wins = array_count_values($winning_team);
    $team_loses = array_count_values($losing_team);
    $team_drawn = array_count_values($drawn_team);  
    $total_goals_scored_by_teams=get_single_team_total2($total_goals_scored);
    $total_goals_condeded_by_teams=get_single_team_total2($total_goals_condeded);

    $total_points=0;
    $team_points=[];
    $team_points2=[];
    $team_points3=[];
    foreach($team_wins as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points[$tw_key]=$tw_val*3;
    }

    foreach($team_drawn as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points2[$tw_key]=$tw_val*1;
    }

    $total_points_final = array();
    $total_points_final2 = array();
    foreach (array_keys($team_points + $team_points2) as $key) {
        $total_points_final[$key] = (isset($team_points[$key]) ? $team_points[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points2[$key]) ? $team_points2[$key] : 0);
    }

    foreach($team_loses as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points3[$tw_key]=$tw_val*0;
    }

    foreach (array_keys($total_points_final + $team_points3) as $key) {
        $total_points_final2[$key] = (isset($total_points_final[$key]) ? $total_points_final[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points3[$key]) ? $team_points3[$key] : 0);
    }
    $result=generate_table_details2($total_matches_played,$team_wins,$team_loses,$team_drawn,$total_goals_scored_by_teams,$total_goals_condeded_by_teams,$total_points_final2);

    if($totalrows_count>0):
    $content.='<table class="leaguetable">';
        $content.='<thead class="leaguetable-head">';
            $content.='<tr>';
                $content.='<th class="pos-head" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Position">Rank</th>';
                $content.='<th class="team-head">Team</th>';
                $content.='<th class="played-head">GP</th>';
                $content.='<th class="own-head">W</th>';
                $content.='<th class="drawn-head">D</th>';
                $content.='<th class="lost-head">L</th>';
                $content.='<th class="gf-head">GF</th>';
                $content.='<th class="ga-head">GA</th>';
                $content.='<th class="gd-head">GD</th>';
                $content.='<th class="points-head">Pts</th>';
                $content.='<th class="qualification-head">Qualification or relegation</th>';
            $content.='</tr>';
        $content.='</thead>';
        $content.='<tbody class="table-body">';
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($result['team_list']);$i++){
            $content.='<tr>'; 


                $win_res;
                if($result['total_wins'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $win_res=$result['total_wins'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $win_res=0;
                }

                $draw_res;
                if($result['team_drawn'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $draw_res=$result['team_drawn'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $draw_res=0;
                }

                $loss_res;
                if($result['total_loses'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $loss_res=$result['total_loses'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $loss_res=0;
                }

                $gf;
                if($result['total_goals_for'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $gf=$result['total_goals_for'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $gf=0;
                }

                $ga;
                if($result['total_goals_against'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $ga=$result['total_goals_against'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $ga=0;
                }

                $tot_points;
                if($result['team_points'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $tot_points=$result['team_points'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $tot_points=0;
                }

                $tot_points;
                if($result['team_points'][$result['team_list'][$i]]!=''){
                    $tot_points=$result['team_points'][$result['team_list'][$i]];
                } else {
                    $tot_points=0;
                }


                $content.='<td class="team-pos" >'.$result['team_postiion'][$result['team_list'][$i]].'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-logo-name"><img src="'.get_team_image_from_title2($result['team_list'][$i]).'"  style="height:30px; width:30px;"/>'.$result['team_list'][$i].'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-played">'.$result['total_matches_played'][$result['team_list'][$i]].'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-win">'.$win_res.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-draw">'.$draw_res.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-loss">'.$loss_res.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-gf">'.$gf.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-ga">'.$ga.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-gd">'.$gd.'</td>';
                $content.='<td class="team-points">'.$tot_points.'</td>';
            $content.='</tr>';
        }
        $content.='</tbody>';
    $content.='</table>';
    else:
        $content='No records found';
    endif;
    echo $content;

    die();
}
```

Comment: your meta comparison should be `EXISTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the CPT that have the `meta_key`, then u can remove `value` and `compare` and it should work.